# Using this vs using variable in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having tough time figuring out when should we preferably use `this` keyword and when shouldn't we use it..

For example, I was earlier doing something like this.

```
let socket; 
class something extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
 socket = openSocket('https://coincap.io');
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  socket.on('trades', (tradeMsg) => {
 }

componentWillUnmount() {
 this.socket.disconnect();
}
```

then someone re-structured my code did something like

```
 class something extends Component {

 componentDidMount() {
    this.socket = openSocket('https://coincap.io');
}

  componentDidUpdate() {
     this.socket.on('trades', (tradeMsg) => {
    }


componentWillUnmount() {
 this.socket.disconnect();
}
```

**[Question:]** While, Both the code works and do the job, I am perplexed between understanding which methods should we use and why did he used `this` keyword?

Comment: If you have two or more instances of `something` you will probably end up having a bad time with the first implementation

Comment: You need to ask yourself "Does this variable belong to an instance?". In your case, I believe you need one `socket` for each instance of `something`, then you should put `socket` as a property of the instance of `something`, otherwise, `socket` could be overridden later when a new `something` is initialized.

Comment: I saw you've updated code in repo - ANY reason to not placing `displaySearchCrypto` in state? Still two kinds of data managing in component?

Answer (score 3):

You are dealing with ES6, which takes out a lot of ambiguity pertaining to the `this` keyword in the language.

Quite simply, `this` means (in the more traditional sense) the **current scope**; *however*, in JavaScript, `this` means the **object calling the function** as opposed to the current scope.

As mentioned previously, ES6 takes out a lot of complexity regarding [variable hoisting](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) and the likes.

Coming to your question, the reason it was refactored to `this.something` was because when your class is called (now, remember, JavaScript follows prototypal inheritance and is a first-class language; meaning that function `prototypes` are the class bases and functions can be passed as parameters) it will act like a function and the `this` keyword will refer to the object or the context where it was called.

If we have the following bit of code:

```
let foo = 'bar';
const fn = () => { console.log( this.foo ); }

fn();
```

The execution context would be `window` and the `foo` variable would be `window.foo`; hence, `this.foo` would translate to `window.foo`.

Similarly, your code will be transpiled something like:

```
var socket = new Socket();
function className() {}

className.prototype.someFunction = function() {

    console.log( socket );

}
```

Here, the `this` keyword would make sure that the current context is used instead of local variables which you might use within your function.

I hope this makes it clear. [Here](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-javascript-the-this-keyword-4de325d77f68) is a great article to understand the `this` keyword! :)

Comment: ,Thanks for such an amazing answer,  What do you mean when you say `prototypes are the class bases`?

Comment: I mean that they form the classes since the ES6 class syntax is just sugar to make stuff more readable; in the end, it all boils down to that. Further, if you have to modify a class (add a function, say), you use the prototype 'myFunction prototype...'

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't the difference between `this` and a variable per se. It's that `this` refers to class instance and allows to have multiple class instances and thus multiple socket instances, while `socket` variable refers to specific socket instance and will be overridden in subsequent component instances.

The component will malfunction if there's more than one component instance at time, because `socket` variable refers to latest `openSocket('https://coincap.io')`  result.

Also, this

```
let socket; 
class something extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
 socket = openSocket('https://coincap.io');
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  socket.on('trades', (tradeMsg) => {
 }

componentWillUnmount() {
 this.socket.disconnect();
}
```

will result in error on component unmount because there's no `this.socket`.